# SQL Join table-valued function with table where table field is a function input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table-valued function called fn_SplitCommaSep, which comma-separates a text field (from 'a, b, c' to 3 rows: a b c)

How can I join this to a table, taking a table column as an input?

For the purpose of this, say the table MyTable has 2 columns, Id and TextWithCommas, and that table-valued function fn_SplitCommaSep produces one column called TextWithoutComma

eg. something like one of these

```
select fs.TextWithoutComma
  from fn_SplitCommaSep(select mt.TextWithCommas from MyTable) fs
```

or

```
select fs.TextWithoutComma, mt.Id
  from MyTable mt
    inner join fn_SplitCommaSep(mt.TextWithCommas) fs on (something)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN with Table-Valued Function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402316/inner-join-with-table-valued-function-not-working)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Storing comma-separated values in a DB aside, take a look at [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

So something like:

```
SELECT fs.TextWithoutComma, mt.Id 
FROM   MyTable mt 
    CROSS APPLY fn_SplitCommaSep(mt.TextWithCommas) AS fs
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I appreciate you taking the time. Point taken with comma-sep values... Boyce-Codd wouldn't be happy, case of the least-worse solution :-)

Comment: I was looking for that whole day... but it works very well. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful