# Is there any way to get column value on the basis of row number?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, rows, traversal

I have a table valued function `[dbo].GetValues()` in my SQL Server database which is written in C#. This function returns a table of integers inside the text specified in the arguments. For example, `[dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3')` will return following table:

```
| Ints |
| ---- |
| 232  |
| 34   |
| 3    |
```

Now I am trying to use this resultant table in a `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE @IntCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3'))
WHILE(@IntCount > 0)
BEGIN
    -- What to do here??
    SET @IntCount = @IntCount - 1
END
```

So, is there any way I can access the rows one by one in this while loop using some index or row number?

Also, please note that I don't have access to the source code of `GetValues()`.

**UPDATE (Actual Problem)**

There are three tables in database A1, A2 and A3. All of these tables has a column [ID] that is foreign key to other table in following way:

```
[A1].[ID] is connected to [A2].[A1ID]
[A2].[ID] is connected to [A3].[A2ID]
```

The text passed as argument to the function contains integers that are the [ID]s of A3 table. Now, I want the rows from A1 and A2 table using the [ID] of A3 table.

I now have all the options suggested by you people including cursors and joins. But which one is more optimized for this situation and how to do it?

Comment: Do you really need a loop here? What are you doing as the body of the loop? Looping in sql is horribly inefficient and can usually be avoided.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually these integers are IDs of some other table rows. I want to fetch each of them one by one and process them.

Comment: @Aishwarya, In that case you *don't* need a loop. You should just need to join the results of GetValues() to the other tables.

Comment: Right but do you need to process them RBAR (row by agonizing row)?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: you can `CROSS APPLY` with the table valued function.

Comment: Similar to what @TimSchmelter said, you can use the function like a table and `INNER JOIN` the results to whatever other table(s) you need to. Look at examples here for [Table-Valued Functions and joining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402316/inner-join-with-table-valued-function-not-working). And like others said, PLEASE don't use loops and cursors!

Comment: Everyone please check my update. I explained the actual situation that I am facing.

Comment: It still is not clear at all what you are doing in the body of the loop. If you can explain that we can quite probably remove the loop entirely.

Comment: So, do you know from the list of ID's returned by the function, which ones are for table A1 vs A2?  If so, then use whatever logic is required, and perform two `JOIN` operations for the two tables.  If you don't know which ones are A1 ID's vs A2 ID's, of if it does not matter, then still do two `JOIN` operations, using the full set of returned ID's (as opposed to using "A1 subset" and "A2 subset" of the returned values).  Same overall logic regarding Table-Valued Functions applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
select * 
from A1
join A2 on [A1].[ID] = [A2].[A1ID]
join A3 on [A2].[ID] = [A3].[A2ID]
join [dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3') V on A3.ID = v.Ints
```

<s>You can use a cursor:</s>

```
 DECLARE @i INT

 DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
 SELECT Ints FROM [dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3')

 OPEN cur

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN

 /* cursor logic -- @i will hold 232, then 34, then 3 */

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

 END

 CLOSE cur
 DEALLOCATE cur
```

If you have those `IDs` in another table you can just join on result of calling table valued function:

```
select * from SomeTable st
join [dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3') ft on st.SomeID = ft.Ints
```

Comment: Won't this unnecessarily call the function for each fetch?

Comment: Can you use `Select *` ? Shouldn't it be `Select ColName`?

Comment: @Kaf, it returns one column called `Ints` as I guess so `*` will work.

Comment: I updated my question. Want to confirm which is more optimized solution.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks. That solved the issue. I am still a newbie to joins so don't know about the possibilities. Challenging situations reveal their possibilities. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to select some records, a simple select can do the job:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(Max) = '232dasdg34vb3'

SELECT A1.Id, A2.Id
FROM A1 
     JOIN A2 ON A1.Id = A2.A1Id
     JOIN A3 ON A2.Id = A3.A2Id
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 
              FROM [dbo].GetValues( @Value ) x 
              WHERE x.Ints = A3.Id
             )
```

Comment: Just curious, what is `@CurrentRecordId`?  The cursor option works, but I haven't seen this before.  Hopefully though, the OP can do this without a loop or a cursor.

Comment: It is a user defined variable, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I updated my question. Want to confirm which is more optimized solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer. All three queries are equally good. Main thing is to avoid the loop or cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use loops or cursors but set based approaches like:

```
SELECT x.Ints, ot.ID, ot.*
FROM OtherTable ot 
WHERE ot.ID IN (SELECT x.Ints FROM [dbo].GetValues('232dasdg34vb3'))
```

Comment: Can you please check my update and tell me which way is more optimized according to my situation?