# SQL custom function calling an other function, shows error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table Disciplines

```
DisciplineID |Discipline_Name
1            |  Aquatics
2            |  Archery
3            |  Athletics
```

I ave a function that takes a string like ("Aquatics, Archery") and returns a table with entries
Aquatics
Archery
(Basically splits string)
the function for that is as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
 @Input NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
  Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT, @Character CHAR(1)
  SET @StartIndex = 1
  SET @Character =','
  IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
  BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
  END
  WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
  BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)
        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)
        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
  END
  RETURN
END
GO
```

Also an other function:

```
create function getdisID
(
 @Inp varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
  Itemid int
   )
as
begin

SELECT DisciplineID
FROM Disciplines
inner JOIN 
dbo.SplitString(@Inp) as temp
ON Disciplines.Discipline_Name=temp.Item;
end
```

The second function upon execution produces an error
"**Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client**".

Comment: I think you want to `apply` rather than `join` the function

Comment: @HoneyBadger could you be a little more clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN with Table-Valued Function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402316/inner-join-with-table-valued-function-not-working)

Comment: You can not use select statement directly in function to return data. You need to insert selected data into output table parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script for second function should be like this:

```
create function getdisID
(
 @Inp varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
  Itemid int
   )
as
begin

insert into @Output
select DisciplineID
FROM Disciplines
inner JOIN 
dbo.SplitString(@Inp) as temp
ON Disciplines.Discipline_Name=temp.Item;
return
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Does this help

```
create function getdisID (@Inp varchar(1000))

Returns Table 
As
Return (
    SELECT DisciplineID
    FROM Disciplines 
    inner JOIN dbo.SplitString(@Inp) as temp
    ON Disciplines.Discipline_Name=temp.Item;
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create function getdisID
(
   @Inp varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
  Itemid int
)
as
begin

INSERT INTO @Output(Itemid)
SELECT DisciplineID
FROM Disciplines
inner JOIN 
dbo.SplitString(@Inp) as temp
ON Disciplines.Discipline_Name=temp.Item;

end
```

You need to either use stored procedure to return result or you need to insert data in output table parameter

Comment: I think you might have forgot the return statement.  But thanks it worked..