# Call table value function inside my query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-function

I create this function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FxPackageReport]
( @packageId int )
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
        select *from TestPackageReportDetails where TestPackageId=@packageId and step='LineCheck'
         )
select *from dbo.fxpackagereport(5457)
```

The result :

[image]

I want to merge this columns inside my select something like this :

```
select id,select *from dbo.fxpackagereport(id), from testpackage
```

Is there any solution to merge this result with my query >?I just want to bring the table result inside my query .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Join table-valued function with table where table field is a function input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764994/sql-join-table-valued-function-with-table-where-table-field-is-a-function-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDF seems rather straight forward so rather than using the UDF, a simple join may due.

```
   Select A.*
          ,B.* 
    From testpackage A
    Join TestPackageReportDetails B
      on (TestPackageId=A.ID and step='LineCheck')
```

Another option would be to use a CROSS APPLY and your UDF

```
select A.id
      ,B.*
from testpackage A
Cross Apply (Select * from dbo.fxpackagereport(A.id)) B
```

Comment: In fact the problem is a little complex ,in this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243771/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-view i get my solution but i want to change this solution to storeprocedure

Comment: I just want to add my row to column

Comment: It works ,I just add multi cross apply .thank you :)

Comment: Just one more question how can i use cross apply like left join ?

Comment: select A.id
      ,B.*
   ,C.*
from TestPackages A
Cross Apply (Select * from dbo.fxpackagereport(A.id,'LineCheck')) B
Cross Apply (Select * from dbo.fxpackagereport(A.id,'Clean')) C

Comment: Because here some values that don't  exist in fxpackagereport table ,but it should be in my output